# question -rotational inertia

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics

[image]

I did:

$v = 0.067 m$ ; $m = 0520$ kg ; I = $\frac{1}{2}mr^2$

Then, $I = \frac{1}{2}0.520kg *0.0620m^2$

Then the answer is: $9.99 * 10^{-4} kg · m^2$

Is that right?

Comment: Please screenshot the image and post it in the question. It's annoying to look at it by pressing the link and then going back to answer the question.

Comment: This question is also better suited for Physics Stack Exchange (https://physics.stackexchange.com/). I'll ask for a moderator to move it.

Comment: @TobyMak No, they will close it. PSE has no HW policy. This question as it stands might get closed here, no hope for it in PSE.

Comment: Not every question unrelated should be closed under the "off topic" guideline.

Comment: The OP's just a new user, you should give him some time to adapt and learn.

Comment: Oh, okay. I'll add the image next time.

Comment: I thought this allowed physics questions. There is a physics tag I clicked

Comment: $I = {1\over2 } mk^2$, $k$ is the radius of gyration not the radius of the object.

Comment: @user442415 Yes it is allowed here.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the distinction. Which number should I place for k?

Comment: @user442415 You don't know $k$. Like for a solid sphere $I = {2\over 5}mr^2$, where $r$ is the radius of sphere. see it does not equal $I = {1\over 2}mr^2$.

Comment: How did you get that value for $v$? By the way, do you see that the velocity is changing with time?

Comment: @user442415 I think you need to use other equations for $I$. Since you know $a$, you know $\alpha$.

Comment: @Andrei I think he is talking about least count of $y$ - axis in the graph.

Comment: @A---B That does not make any sense. If the full axis is $4.0 m/s$, at $t=1s$ the velocity is $v=3.5m/s$

Comment: I'm very confused. So, my answer was wrong? How can I solve it?

Comment: There is no solution unless the object's shape is explicitly given.

Comment: In other words, your question is too vague.

Comment: I'm trying to solve the question in the image. It asks for rotational inertia. How is this vague?

Answer (score 2):

The moment of inertia of a hollow cylindrical shell of radius $0.0620$ of mass $0.520,$ whose mass is all on the curved surface of the cylinder, is 
$9.99 \times 10^{-4}.$

But you were not told that the object rolling down the incline is a cylinder whose mass is all on its curved surface. The mass *might* all be there, or it might mostly be in the center of the object, or it might be distributed in any other manner throughout the object.

The outer radius of the object and its mass are simply not enough information to tell you its rotational inertia.

Notice that you did not use the velocity of the object at all, nor any information about the incline.

There are a couple of ways to approach this problem:

- By considering the force accelerating the object down the incline, the rate of acceleration of the object (both the linear acceleration and the rotational acceleration), and the forces required to produce both of those accelerations (which must add up to the force exerted). If you set up the relevant equation correctly, the rotational inertia will be the only unknown; solve for it.
- By considering conservation of energy. The object starts from zero linear and rotational velocity, and after descending some vertical distance, has traded some potential energy for kinetic energy. If you set up the energy equation correctly,  the rotational inertia will be the only unknown; solve for it.

In either case you will need to use the slope of the incline and the graph of the speed in order to find the necessary data.